# Adding a preview product section on the product page

Tags: module, layout, template, layout-update, custom-block

I am fairly new to the Magento platform so excuse my lack of knowledge!


I'm working on a Magento 2 project.

I need to add a preview section for my products.[image: preview of product section]
Ideally, it would be between the product-info-main and the product-info-detailed. I'm looking to place this:
[My Flipbook Preview ([iCatalogue Module](https://github.com/maciejslawik/icatalogue-magento2))](http://magento-150747-474271.cloudwaysapps.com/icatalogue/catalogue/view/id/3)


I understand I would need to create a template file for this and add the block to the product page. I am reading/studying layouts, blocks and templates ([devdocs - customizing layouts](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html)). To help speed up my learning, could someone point me in the right direction or let me know the best practice for customizing a layout page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the block over the tabs on a product page from your module you need to create `MODULE_ROOT/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.block.name" template="Your_Module::preview.phtml" after="product.info.media" before="product.info.details"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Consider specifying appropriate block **class and template** references in the code snippet.

Example of block rendering:
[image]